# How to resolve "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" error

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I'm trying to install MySQL on OS X.

First I tried MacPorts.  I followed the instructions in step 3 of https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP, but when I ran mysqladmin5 or mysql5 I get:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (61)

The file mysqld.sock existed.

Then I tried installing using a .dmg from mysql.com.  (I ran port uninstall mysql5-server first.)  Now, I get:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock'

How can I fix this?  I see that a lot of questions deal with this, but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

Comment: You said that the file `mysqld.sock` exists. What about its permissions?

Comment: I ran chmod a=rwx mysqld.sock and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you haven't started MySQL server:

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
```

Comment: The output is "404 ??         0:00.09 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=mysql5 --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper restart ; --pid=none"